# Create local DeltaTable without writing to disk for testing purposes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I'm trying to write an unit test for a `merge` operation on a `DeltaTable` that I have. So far the approach has been to save the contents of a `DataFrame` to a local file so that it can then be read via `DeltaTable.forPath(...)`

```
Seq(MyData(column_1 = "column_1_value", column_2 = "column_2_value").toDF()
   .write.format("Delta").save(location)

val table = DeltaTable.forPath(location)

//execute code to be tested (includes a merge)

val resultOfMerge = table.toDF

//verify results of merge are correct
```

The problem is that takes too long, +20 seconds, sometimes +30 seconds. Is there a way I can construct a `DeltaTable` with sample data and avoid the time consuming write and read operations to disk?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I've noticed the same behavior. When compared to plain parquet storage, delta is more than 2x slower for just 1-5 records.

Comment: @theDataNerd I'm afraid I haven't, what a mistery, should be something easy